Certificate issue that only affects one computer for only one server webapp
We have a local server webapp that's giving me certificate issues. The odd thing though, is that it's only happening on this one webapp, and also only on this computer. Other users are able to connect without any issues, and for the computer in question - there are no issues with any other websites or server webapps. I'm used to seeing a lot of issues for one computer, or everyone having the same issue with a website/webapp, but not just isolated to one combination like this.
Firefox: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
Edge: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
I can continue past these errors as I know they're secure sites, but other aspects of the webapp do not seem to load, or have other certificate errors.
Does anyone have recommendations for how to start diagnosing this? My main suspicion is that there's some sort of issue with a root signature, but I've struggled to work it out. We've tried importing the certificate manually but there was no difference. I have a number of extensions on Firefox, but none at all on Edge. Could other software be impacting it (eg. VPNs - though they are obviously turned off)?
What I've tried:
Different computers (works)
Checking different sites or webapps on the same network (all work fine)
Different browser on problem computer (doesn't work)
Date and time is correct
Importing certificate manually

Solved this today with the help of one of our consultants. The issue seems to be that, though my laptop is able to connect to the servers here when on the main wifi network (or via VPN), it isn't fully on the domain so isn't receiving the certificates automatically. We'd tried manually importing a certificate before, but it must have not been the correct root cert. We've tried manually importing a couple now and the problem seems to be solved.
